# How do I set up a connection string for a MySQL database in a C# project without using dialog boxes?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, entity-framework, datasource

*NOTE: Apparently, the reason the MySQL connector installation doesn't show up automatically in the Dialog Boxes for adding a data source is because the* ***Visual 2008 Express Edition*** *doesn't allow "3rd party integration" within the Visual Studio IDE. So, this makes setting up the data source manually even more important because the integrated tools from the MySQL connector aren't present.*

---

My goal is to set up a connection to a MySQL database using Entity Framework (an ADO.NET Entity Data Model). I'm getting frustrated by all the wizards and dialog boxes and I still can't find what I'm looking for.

Here's what I've done so far: I just installed the MySQL .NET Connector v6.1.3 on my machine (to my knowledge, it is correctly installed.  It shows up in Add/Remove Programs in the Control Panel).  In Visual Studio (Visual C# 2008 Express Edition SP1 with Entity Framework Version that ships with SP1), I click to add a reference to a project, click on "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" and that brings me to a screen that asks "What should the model contain?"  I select "Generate from database" and then click Next.

This screen asks me which data connection I should use.  I click "New Connection" and get a screen that looks like this:

[image]

Where's an option for the ADO.NET MySQL Connector that I just installed?

I know [where to find the connection string](http://connectionstrings.com/mysql#p28) for MySQL, but I can't figure out how to get it into my application so that Visual studio recognizes it, uses the ADO.NET connector, and allows me to select that connection to create an Entity Model.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the app.config (or web.config) file to add a  entry. Be sure the specify the provider= attribute correctly with the MySQL provider.

Comment: Here is an example for JET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243192.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for third-party extensions in Visual C# 2008 Express 
Edition SP1.

This is mentioned in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/danielfe/archive/2007/05/31/visual-studio-express-and-testdriven-net.aspx) by Dan Fernandez.

More information about the difference between Express and Professional 
editions is available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en) in the Visual Studio 2008 Product Comparison article.

Comment: Does the MySQL ADO.NET Connector constitute a 3rd party extension?  I think it's just a series of assemblies in the Global Assembly Cache when installed, but perhaps I'm incorrect.

Comment: Apparently the MySQL Connector does in fact install "Visual Studio Integration" when it is installed.  I suppose that keeps MySQL from showing up in the Database explorer.  Is there no way to set it up manually without going through all of the dialog boxes then?

Comment: Visual C# 2008 Express Edition does not allow even to create a design-time connection to the MS SQL Server instance. This is a limitation of a free product. <br />
So, neither MySQL ADO.NET 
Connector/NET, nor Devart dotConnect for MySQL cannot be used in design time in bundle with the Express version. <br />
You can try to work around the situation - try the console tool like <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx">EdmGen</a> or <a href="http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2">EdmGen2</a>

Comment: correct links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx
and http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2