# Is it possible to use Entity Framework with MySQL in the Visual Studio Express Editions?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework

Since 3rd party integration is not allowed in Visual Studio Express Editions, MySQL doesn't show up as an option for adding a data source to the Database Explorer (or Server Explorer?) in Visual C# 2008 Express Editions.  This makes it incredibly confusing to try [to configure MySQL to work with Entity Framework when you can't use dialog boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863348/how-do-i-set-up-a-connection-string-for-a-mysql-database-in-a-c-project-without).

**Is it even possible to use Entity Framework with MySQL in the Visual Studio Express Editions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio Express as a compiler and work with the Entity Framework models using third-party tools. Try the console tool like [EDMGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx) or [EdmGen2](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2).