# MySQL not Listed in Updated model from Database for entity framework in VS Express 2012 edition

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-express

i am trying to update model from database and use  MySQL as my data source, it seems like there is some problem in listing MySQL as datasource .
Please see the inline image :
[image: MySQL not listed in Update model from db]
I have installed MySQL for visual studio , that way i am able to see the existing data model,created by someone else,
but i can't update the data model.
Also i tried the solution given here :
[Can't Create Entity Data Model - using MySql and EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241500/cant-create-entity-data-model-using-mysql-and-ef6) , but it didn't worked out .

It seems like there is some problem with VS 2012 express edition.

I need to know is this an issue with VS 2012 express , or am I missing something,

How to list MySQL as the data source ??
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, VS 2012 Express doesn't supported by `MySQL for Visual Studio` as extension but supported by `MySQL Connector/NET`, according to [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html):

> MySQL for Visual Studio does not support Express versions of Microsoft
>   development products, including the Visual Studio and the Microsoft
>   Visual Web Developer.
>
> To use MySQL Connector/Net with an Express versions of Microsoft development products, use MySQL Connector/Net 6.7.4 or later, without installing the MySQL for Visual Studio.

Here are some steps to use Connector/NET with EF:

1. Install MySQL Connector/NET, add 3 following DLL files as reference in your project:

   ```
   MySql.Data.dll
   MySql.Data.Entity.dll (for EF6 it should be MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll)
   MySql.Web.dll
   ```

The required files exist on `MySQL\MySQL Connector Net [version number]\Assemblies\[.NET version]\`, e.g. `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.x.x\Assemblies\v4.5\`.

2. Change `entityFramework` element on your `web.config` file depending on EF version being used:

**EF 5**

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity" />
</entityFramework>
```

**EF 6**

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" /> 
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

3. **Rebuild** your project/solution and ensure "MySQL Database" option is available on data source dropdown list.

**Update:**

After conducting further research regarding data source availability, I found that Visual Studio Express editions have certain set of limitations regarding third party extensions, hence in some cases doesn't allow even creating connection to MySQL instance in EDM design-time (thanks to [Devart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863348/how-do-i-set-up-a-connection-string-for-a-mysql-database-in-a-c-sharp-project-wi) reminds me about this). As a workaround, CLI-based EDM Generator may be used (see [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896270.aspx) and [usage description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx)) like this example:

```
edmgen.exe /mode:fullgeneration /c:"[MySQL DB connection string]" /project:[project name] /entitycontainer:[entity name] /namespace:[table namespace] /language:CSharp
```

Related issues:

[mySQL DataSource on Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684047/mysql-datasource-on-visual-studio-2012)

[Can't use a MySQL connection for entity framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206184/cant-use-a-mysql-connection-for-entity-framework-6)

[MySQL For Visual Studio 2012/2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664663/mysql-for-visual-studio-2012-2013)

Comment: So this method will not work in VS 2012 express, I tried but didn't worked for me

Comment: What steps you have tried and when it was not working? I want to know if you've done something wrong or incorrect during Connector Net integration.

Comment: I have followed the steps as explained project gets build , but in data source it doesn't gets listed . I have referred the Dlls properly . are you sure it works for VS Express 2012

Comment: Well, after further researches I found that VS Express editions have some limitations about third party extensions integration - you can use EdmGen (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx) as a workaround to build EF data model.

Comment: Thanks ! , Let me try that solution also  .

Comment: Updated with some info. Even it can't utilize design-time code generation, it may use connection string to generate EDM table classes.